# Static call of non-static methods

Tags: methods, rust

For various reasons I like calling regular methods as if they were static, e.g., not using the dot notation.  (For example, `Vec::len( &v )` instead of `v.len()`.)  I can always do this with my own methods;  however, with some methods that belong to the standard library I cannot do it for some reason.  For example, `Vec::binary_search( &v, &t )` does not compile ("no function or associated item named `binary_search` found for struct `std::vec::Vec<_>` in the current scope"), even when `v.binary_search( &t )` does.  Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

That is because [`binary_search` is a method of *slices*, not of `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search).

It is available on `Vec` because [`Vec` *derefs* to slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-22), and method calls auto-deref (that's also why you can call methods of `T` on a `Box<T>` or an `&T`, despite those methods not being implemented on `Box` or references).

Answer (score 1):

`binary_search` isn't implemented in `Vec`. The call `v.binary_search(...)` works because of the `Deref<Target=[T]>` and [`binary_search` is implemented on `[T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search).

Here's how make it work as an associated function.

```rust
<[_]>::binary_search(&v, &t);
```